# Add a new column if multiple columns have negative value

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I am trying to add a new column "result" in my dataframe df1, if the condition is

1. select only specific columns (from count1:count3 columns) have negative value, then result = "negative"
2. if any one of the columns (count1, count2, count3) have a positive value the result = "positive"

input

```
df1<- data.frame(ID= c("ID1","ID2","ID3","ID4"), count1 = c(1,-1,0,-1), count2 = c(1,-1,-1,1), count3 = c(1,-1,1,-1))
```

expected output

```
df2 <- data.frame(ID= c("ID1","ID2","ID3","ID4"),count1 = c(1,-1,1,-1), count2 = c(1,-1,-1,1), count3 = c(1,-1,1,-1), result = c("positive","negative","positive","positive"))

  ID count1 count2 count3   result
 ID1      1      1      1 positive
 ID2     -1     -1     -1 negative
 ID3      1     -1      1 positive
 ID4     -1      1     -1 positive
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work:

```
apply(df1,1,function(x) if(all(x > 0)) 'positive' else 'negative')
[1] "positive" "negative" "negative" "negative"

library(dplyr)
df1 %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(result = if_else(all(c_across(cols = everything()) > 0),'positive','negative'))
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Rowwise: 
  count1 count2 count3 result  
   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>   
1      1      1      1 positive
2     -1     -1     -1 negative
3      0     -1      1 negative
4     -1      1     -1 negative
```

Comment: i edited my question. I only want to select specific columns, eg from column 2 to 4.

Comment: You can include only those columns in both solutions, i.e. `df1[2:4]` in `apply` and `c_across(2:4)` accordingly.

Comment: that worked fine. But the condition is if any one of the column have positive value the results should be positive, and not negative. It should report negative only if all the three columns have value < 0. My apology for not explaining it clearly

Comment: @Kryo, ah ok, please change `all` to `any` in that case in both solutions

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(results = if_else(apply(df1, 1, min) < 0, "negative", "positive"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using *rowSums*:

```
df1$results <- ifelse(rowSums(df1[ grepl("^count", colnames(df1)) ] > 0) > 0,
                      "positive", "negative")


df1
#    ID count1 count2 count3  results
# 1 ID1      1      1      1 positive
# 2 ID2     -1     -1     -1 negative
# 3 ID3      0     -1      1 positive
# 4 ID4     -1      1     -1 positive
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` option

```
setDT(df1)[, result := c("negative", "positive")[1 + (rowSums(.SD == 1) > 0)], .SDcols = patterns("count")][]
```

gives

```
    ID count1 count2 count3   result
1: ID1      1      1      1 positive
2: ID2     -1     -1     -1 negative
3: ID3      0     -1      1 positive
4: ID4     -1      1     -1 positive
```

Comment: last 2 row should be positive  and not negative