# Mutate a new columns based positive and negative consistency of two columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to add a new column `result` in my dataframe `df1`, as specific columns (`value1` and `value2` columns) met the following conditions:

1. Both of them row-wisely are positive, negative or 0, or one of them is 0 and
   another is either negative or positive, then `result=="True"`;
2. if row-wisely one of them are positive and another is negative or verse versa, then
   `result=="False"`;
3. if row-wisely both of them are `NA`s or one of them is `NA` but
   another is either negative or positive, then `result=="-"`

Input:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID= c("ID1","ID2","ID3","ID4","ID5"), value1 = c(1.2, -1, NA, -1.5, 0), value2 = c(0.8, -1.1, -1, 1.3, 0.9))
```

Expected output:

```
df2 <- data.frame(ID= c("ID1","ID2","ID3","ID4","ID5"), value1 = c(1.2, -1, NA, -1.5, 0), value2 = c(0.8, -1.1, -1, 1.3, 0.9), result = c("True","True","-", "False", 'True'))
```

Out:

[image]

Any helps would be appreciated.

Reference link:

[Add a new column if multiple columns have negative value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67918036/add-a-new-column-if-multiple-columns-have-negative-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(result = case_when(
    is.na(value1 * value2) ~ "-",
    value1 * value2 >=0 ~ "True",
    T ~ "False"
  ))

   ID value1 value2 result
1 ID1    1.2    0.8   True
2 ID2   -1.0   -1.1   True
3 ID3     NA   -1.0      -
4 ID4   -1.5    1.3  False
5 ID5    0.0    0.9   True
```

Comment: Very smart solution by using multiply, thanks a lot.